# Updated Regarding of Appointment not reflecting in Account's Activities

Tags: dynamics-crm-online

I have an Account wherein 2 Appointments appear in the Activities section. I updated the regarding of those Appointments to point to different Accounts. However, the Appointment still shows in Activities of the Account it belonged to originally. Also, this Appointment shows in the new Regarding Account.

Additionally, the owner of the Account record has been disabled in CRM. Could this be a reason for this? Kindly help.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please make a screenshot of modified Appointment and publish it here?

Comment: Hi.... I don't have enough reputation yet on StackOverflow to be able to post Screenshots...

Comment: Then put it somewhere and post url on image here.

Comment: The account is probably still in required or optional attendees.

Answer (score 0):

To change the relation completely, have to change the participants in the appointment as well as the regarding attribute, otherwise it will be related to the original account

Hope it helps - M.Acosta.D